# 502 bad request on AWS Spring boot application

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi I am new AWS and trying to deploy spring boot application in Elastic Beanstalk . Deployment is successful but not able to access application .Getting 502 Bad Request Gateway nginx/1.10.1 error. Deployment is done on Configuration
64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.2.0 running Java 8 (nginx proxy server). Is thier any way to solve this issue. After doing googling i found it is because of port mismatch.I wanted to know where i should change the port numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java AWS Server: 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491744/java-aws-server-502-bad-gateway-nginx-1-8-1)

Comment: Just to validate if it is a nginx error, could you try to consume your spring boot using curl behind balancer? I mean at inside your ec2 instance... curl http://localhost:port/rest_controller_endpoint

Answer (score 10):

From AWS [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/):

> By default, Spring Boot applications will listen on port 8080. Elastic
>   Beanstalk assumes that the application will listen on port 5000. There
>   are two ways to fix this discrepancy: change the port Elastic
>   Beanstalk is configured to use, or change the port the Spring Boot
>   application listens on.

You can set the port in `server.port` property in `application.properties` or set it through environment as described in the document referred above by setting SERVER_PORT environment property.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. And the reason was the fact that i didn't correctly generate my jar. Instead of taking the classic jar from an clean install take the one from a clean package spring-boot:repackage

Answer (score 0):

For me setting `PORT` (instead of `SERVER_PORT`) as environment variable with value `8080` worked for me.